# How do I load a custom font?

Tags: html, css, fonts

My font is http://www.dafont.com/milasian-circa.font?text=

I saved the TTF in the same folder as the HTML file

My CSS looks like

```
@font-face { font-family: 'Milasian Circa PERSONAL'; src: url('MilasianCircaMediumPERSONAL.TTF'); } 

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
    margin: .67em 0;    
    text-align: center;    
    color: FloralWhite;
    font-family: 'Milasian Circa PERSONAL','Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

In my html file

```
<h1><span>Test Message</span></h1><br><h3><span>Wednesday, October 28, 2015</span></h3>
```

I expected my custom font to show but it didn't. It's showing Arial

Comment: The font needs to be in the same directory as the CSS file

Comment: Oh that explains a lot

Comment: Is my font-family name correct?

Comment: It doesn't, you just need to change the src url to point to wherever you've saved the font file.

Comment: Everything else looks correct to me.

Comment: @DAC84 based on how he's declaring the font in src: url(), the reason it's not working is because it's expecting it to be in the same directory.

Comment: What does the browser say about the request to download the font when you load the page?  200 / 404 response?

Comment: @jonsuh sure, based on that code it does but your comment read like it _has_ to be in order to work.

Comment: Not all browsers will recognise the TTF format though; which one are you testing with?

Comment: The CSS is on the same folder that your HTML file? 
Following your code, the TTF need be put in the same folder that your CSS file.

Comment: Internet Explorer versions 8 to 10

Comment: I'm going to move the font to the css folder. But right now it's in the root (where html file is). I wanted to keep my fonts in /fonts instead of /css

Comment: So yes, including @DAC84's comment, you can indeed change the url() to point to the correct directory as well.

Comment: IE8 does not do ttf fonts. See [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#search=ttf). Also, I see in your HTML source that you have spans in the h1 and h3; make sure the spans don't have font-family defined themselves.

Comment: @softwareisfun then link to it like: `url('../fonts/MilasianCircaMediumPERSONAL.TTF');`

Comment: the span is for animation (text animation) only thing defined is the font-size and color

Comment: I guess the font is not compatible with IE11, IE10 (haven't really tested 9/8). It loads fine in Chrome. In IE, it reverts to the 2nd choice.Thanks to all for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Use this link, it will create the fonts in various formats for use and also give you the html code to use

http://www.font2web.com/

Comment: Why was this downvoted? Even though it is just linking, it answers the question.

Comment: its ok @PraveenKumar. Maybe the person who downvoted did not want this answer :)